# Series for finding compound interest

Tags: math, computer-science

I've been given the problem of finding the total amount in a back account after x years if you add y amount of money and it gains z% of interest each year.

The equation to find the total amount is
F = Y[(1+z/100)+(1+z/100)^2+...+(1+z/100)^x]

I'm trying to find a way to complete this using recursion without having to call the pow() function. I thought I might be able to use a series to figure this out so I came to the conclusion that 
f(x) = f(x-1) + f(x-1)*(1+z/100)
I then realized the entire series was being multiplied by (1+z/100), which isn't what I wanted. I was hoping someone could give me a hand figuring out the series, if it's even possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not hard. May be  [geometric progression?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression)

```
Let (1+z/100)=q
q+q^2+...+q^x=(q-q^x)/(1-q)
```

Comment: You're still using exponents.